# ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am running my node js server which makes use of WebSocket but on execution it says "ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined". I am new to to this and am unable to understand why this happening - how do I resolve this?

Comment: how are you calling the socket? Are you using `socket.io`?

Comment: You'll need to show some code associated with this, otherwise this question will be closed since it is way too broad.

Comment: I am just using the code from elsewhere where WebSocket is referenced like this -  "var socket = new WebSocket(this.getUrl());" I don't see require('socket.io') anywhere. The code comes from https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs and should ideally work with node

Comment: maybe this can help you: [link]https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs/issues/80

Comment: @Stat7 That sounds like client code.  You're getting that error from `node.js`?

Answer (score 26):

I think you're getting that line from [this file](https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs/blob/master/leap.js), right?  You're missing the line:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
```

which means you'll need to install `ws` with npm (`npm install ws`).